# Authorization via Facebook Android app without Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I need to implement import Facebook contacts in my app. All, what I needed -- get list of ids Facebook friends.

I can use official SDK for Android, but it's too large and too heavy for such a simple task like this. I can build and send request manually, it's easy. I also can obtain `access_token` using oAuth Facebook authorization in WebView.

But I want to add a little convenience to the user. Facebook Android SDK supports obtaining token via Facebook Android App. I suppose, this mechanism using `Intent` and `onActivityResult` to transfer data between two processes. So in this case I can build same `Intent` and send it to Facebook to handle `access_token`.

Off course, they can use any other mechanism to transfer data between processes, but it's still must be a way to simulate token request fron Facebook Android SDK. So how to simulate this?